# assemblybinding does not work in mstest

Tags: mstest, visual-studio-2012

I have a very simple MSTest unit test project that indirectly have dependency on two versions of MVC.

assemblybinding in app.config is configured to redirect to MVC v4

when I run mstest test runner (VS2012 RC built-in) - I get exception indicating that assembly binding did not work.

If I create testsettings file and disable deployment (or enable deployment and add app.config to the list of items to deploy) - test passes.

**Question:** why does assemblybinding works with deployment set to false? Can I make this test pass without using testsettings file?

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same thing with vs2012, mstest and R#, seems to be a confirmed bug according to this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/234926d1-42c0-4ebb-af39-1626e72f6c39

Adding link to the same bug report in R#:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-329567