# Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient requires incorrect version of dependencies

Tags: nuget, mstest, azure-active-directory, nuget-spec

In Asp.Net Core solution targeted to 4.6.1 full Framework I am using 2.1.1 Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.dll

In MSTest tests library TestMethods I am getting exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.6.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The wild thing that nuspec requires version 5.6.4, but DLL actually references 5.6.3.

Extract from dotPeek:

```
// Assembly Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient, Version=2.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// Assembly references:
// Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// Microsoft.Data.Edm, Version=5.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

.nuget\packages\Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient\2.1.1\Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.nuspec

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.6.4" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.4" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.4" />
      <dependency id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.4" />
    </dependencies>
```

I've tried to install Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.3, but NuGet reported that   Microsoft.Data.Odata requires  5.6.4
I've tried to install Microsoft.Data.Odata  5.6.3, but NuGet reported that   Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient require  5.6.4

I tried to use assemblyBinding, but it doesn't work for me (I've tried suggestions from [assemblybinding does not work in mstest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268547/assemblybinding-does-not-work-in-mstest))

Any suggestions how to make Microsoft.Data.Services.Client loaded?
Can I somehow overwrite nuspec dependencies?

Update:  I've created [isolated library with single TestMethod](https://github.com/MNF/Samples/tree/master/UnitTestProjectVS2017_AADGraphClient), that has the problem.

**The FIX:**
The problem was that in app.config in assemblyBinding/ bindingRedirect I've used File Version instead of Assembly Version, which is different for this assembly 
(File Version=5.6.4.62175, but Assembly Version=5.6.4.0). Correct configuration is

```
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am testing using Visual Studio 2017, and install the package `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` with version `2.1.1`. I also check the dependency version of `Microsoft.Data.Services.Client` is version `5.6.3` as you mentioned.

However, I also checked the version of Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll in the bin folder is `5.6.4.0` and it works well for me. Please use this version to see whether it is helpful.

And here is the part of `deps.json` file for your reference:

```
 {
      "runtimeTarget": {
        "name": ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1/win7-x86",
        "signature": "d7dc1119a66d1c2bf3e9f2c55e2b0432742f00d1"
      },
      "compilationOptions": {
        "defines": [
          "TRACE",
          "DEBUG",
          "NET461"
        ],
        "languageVersion": "",
        "platform": "x86",
        "allowUnsafe": false,
        "warningsAsErrors": false,
        "optimize": false,
        "keyFile": "",
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "xmlDoc": false,
        "debugType": "portable"
      },
      "targets": {
        ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1": {
          "consoleapp1/1.0.0": {
            "dependencies": {
              "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.3",
              "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient": "2.1.1"
            },
            "compile": {
              "ConsoleApp1.exe": {}
            }
          },
          ...
          "microsoft.azure.activedirectory.graphclient/2.1.1": {
            "dependencies": {
              "Microsoft.Data.Edm": "5.6.4",
              "Microsoft.Data.OData": "5.6.4",
              "Microsoft.Data.Services.Client": "5.6.4",
              "System.Spatial": "5.6.4"
            },
            "compile": {
              "lib/portable-net4+sl5+win+wpa+wp8/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.dll": {}
            }
          },
          "microsoft.data.edm/5.6.4": {
            "compile": {
              "lib/net40/Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll": {}
            }
          },
          "microsoft.data.odata/5.6.4": {
            "dependencies": {
              "Microsoft.Data.Edm": "5.6.4",
              "System.Spatial": "5.6.4"
            },
            "compile": {
              "lib/net40/Microsoft.Data.OData.dll": {}
            }
          },
          "microsoft.data.services.client/5.6.4": {
            "dependencies": {
              "Microsoft.Data.OData": "5.6.4"
            },
            "compile": {
              "lib/net40/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll": {}
            }
          },
         ...
        }
      }
    }
```

### Update

For the redirecting assembly in a unit test project, add the config like steps below:

1 .add a config file testAssemblyName.dll.config(eg. my project's name is ConsoleApp1.Test then the config file should be ConsoleApp1.Test.dll.config) with content below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

2. change the property `Copy to Output Directory` with the value `Copy if newer` to make sure that the config is copy to the **bin/debug** folder.

After that the tests run successfully.

Comment: Have  you used an exe  or MSTest tests library? I've created isolated library with single TestMethod, that still has the same problem (https://github.com/MNF/Samples/tree/master/UnitTestProjectVS2017_AADGraphClient).  Also I couldn't see deps.json file (I've tried PreserveCompilationContext both true and false)

Comment: Yes, I tested in an .net core console app( works well since there is a config for the redirecting assembly). And then I test this issue in a unit test and able to reproduce this issue. After I add the config for redirecting assembly, the issue was fixed. Please see the updated post for the detail.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Is the issue fixed?

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I've used version="5.6.4.62175" that was shown as file version and product version in file explorer DLL properties and it  was ignored. When I changed to "5.6.4.0" as in your snippet, it's working. Thanks.

Comment: This solution works very well in my console app, however, when I tried to do the same thing in web.config from an asp.net web form project, it doesn't work over there :(